# Cannot delete Program Files to create a Symlink... Says I need permission from myself?

Tags: windows, windows-7, symlink

Trying to move my program files to a drive B: and leaving a symlink pointing to it in C:

I have copied the folder, however when I try to delete the one in C:, windows says I need permission from myself to delete the folder. I have already set myself as owner and given full control. What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: I can understand relocating "Users" and "ProgramData" off the system drive, but why "Program Files"? Do you have such a small system drive that it's worth this headache?

Comment: @eryksun The same issue develops when I try moving ProgramData, so I assumed the same cause was at play. But yes, I would rather move my programs to another drive, leaving only the bare windows files on C:

Answer (score 0):

press Start Menu(Windows Logo) and Typing `regedit`, run as administrator;
Open:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->Windows->CurrentVersion
```

in the right, modify first letter from `ProgramFilesDir`

Comment: Can the same be used for Program Files (x86) and ProgramData?

Comment: modify first letter from ProgramFilesDir (x86)